# What is the effect of dlls not being signed

Tags: windows-7, dll, code-signing

On running [SigCheck](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441) on my Windows box, I noticed quite a few dlls that are ***unsigned***.
For eg:

```
c:\windows\system32\amdocl64.dll:
        Verified:       Unsigned
        File date:      10:47 AM 9/14/2011
        Publisher:      Advanced Micro Devices Inc.
        Description:    AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing OpenCL 1.1 Runtime
        Product:        OpenCL 1.1 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 (732.1)
        Version:        2, 5, 732, 1
        File version:   2, 5, 732, 1
c:\windows\system32\amdoclcl64.dll:
        Verified:       Unsigned
        File date:      10:38 AM 9/14/2011
        Publisher:      Advanced Micro Devices Inc.
        Description:    AMD COMPILER OpenCL 1.1 Compiler
        Product:        AMD Compiler Library 1.1 AMD-COMP-LIB-v0.7 (727.0)
        Version:        0, 7, 727, 0
        File version:   0, 7, 727, 0
```

But I downloaded the executables from the the official AMD website. Why wouldn't AMD sign their dlls? Are their any security issues I need to be worried about, considering the fact that these (among many others, including vendors like HP) are *unsigned*

Comment: Any chance you've installed beta drivers?

Comment: I doubt that. Let me double check anyway.

Comment: No, they are stable releases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The effect is that you are using a driver that has not been authenticated by a third party as coming from the source it purports to be.

Getting drivers signed costs money and takes time to get, If the company is releasing drivers regularly they may not want to spend that money on signing the latest and greatest version every time.

From Microsoft's [Driver Signing Requirements for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487317):

> Digital signatures allow administrators and end users who are
>   installing Windows-based software to know whether a legitimate
>   publisher has provided the software package.

Generally, if you trust the source you got it from, there should be no concern.

Comment: AMD drivers are normally WHQL signed.

Comment: @ragnq Agreed, but AMD was just the OP's example.

Comment: @techie007, like you said I just showed AMD examples. But there a so many dlls by HP, that haven't been updated in a long time and are still unsigned. I'd expect HP to take that more seriously.

Answer (score -1):

this may mean the dlls might have been altered, but it is normally no effect except if it is a malware. example, game installers copy their versions of a dll instead of the system default dll so the dll is unsigned. or if you edit a dll. or a system restore by using other engine than the system restore tool in windows. there are plenty of cases, but with a good protection don't worry.